# LINQ attempts to truncate variable value to length of comparison

Tags: linq, sql-server-ce

The where clause in the LINQ statement below causes the following error when 'logLevel' has a value of "Error"

- Error message = An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
- Inner exception = p_linq_2 : String truncation: max=3, len=5, value='Error'

If I change `&& (logLevel == "All" || logLevel == "Error")` to `&& (logLevel == "Error")` the error no longer occurs.

It seems that to do the comparison against "All", LINQ tries to truncate the value in 'logLevel' to 3 characters first?

What is going on here?

(I'm running MVC 4, SQL CE 4)

```
IQueryable<LogEvent> list = (from a in _context.ELMAH_Error
    where a.TimeUtc >= start && a.TimeUtc <= end
    && (logLevel == "All" || logLevel == "Error")
    select new LogEvent
    {
    IdType = "guid", Id = "",IdAsInteger = 0,IdAsGuid = a.ErrorId,LoggerProviderName = "Elmah",LogDate = a.TimeUtc,MachineName = a.Host,Message = a.Message,Type = a.Type,Level = "Error",Source = a.Source,StackTrace = ""
    });
```

Comment: Linq-to-what is this?

Comment: Linq-to-entities (_context is a DBContext object) ... should I post up more code? (DBContext class, ELMAH_Error class, etc?)

Comment: Didn't you make a mistake, shouldn't it be `a.logLevel`?

Comment: If not, you should evaluate the value of `logLevel` in your c# code and decide whether you do or don't execute the query.

Comment: logLevel is a parameter of the method in which the above code is in

Comment: Then I'd say you should decide in code whether or not you execute the query at all. Why would you transfer this decision to the Db engine? It is a useless roundtrip for values other than "All" and "Error". Return an `Enumerable.Empty<LogEvent>()` for other values.

Comment: OK.  However - I was wanting to understand _why_ LINQ truncates the value when attempting a comparison...

Comment: Yes of course, that's why I don't consider this an answer. I think it's just a bug. Does it also happen when you put "Error" in front?

Comment: Yes, still get the same error.  Bug then?

Comment: That, or maybe a use case that was never supported. BTW I noticed that doing a similar thing with Entity Framework and Sql Server the whole condition is left out of the SQL query and (apparently) evaluated in memory.

Comment: @jag did you find any solution to this problem?